# Check for coherency in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with elements like this:

1_elem1
2_elem2
3_elem3

Now I want to check if something in that structure is out of place. Out of place means:

1. The numbers in front are not succeeding
2. Numbers are missing

Whats the shortest way to do that in PHP? I thought of sorting the array and check if each element starts with a number. That would solve 2. I am not sure how to do 1. though.

Comment: Just loop over the array and check for each value if it starts with a number and if this number is greater than the number of the previous element. Thats a O(N) operation and you can't do it faster.

Comment: Maybe not faster, but shorter?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "shorter"?

Comment: @user1856596 If you can show the code how you would solve item 2 , it probably would need small modification to solve item 1 . Please show what you have done till now .

Answer (score 1):

If you can solve the 2nd problem, then you could check if the number is equivalent to the index of the array, taking into account the number of missing numbers up to that point.

Meaning that, the index of each element should be equal to the number in front.
Except when there has been a number missing in the past elements, but if you take that into account, you could include a incrementor and subtract that value.

Answer (score 0):

That's a kind of combination of both arrays and regular expressions.

```
<?php
$arr = array( // here is our array
    "1_elem1",
    "4_elem2", // here is an unexpected value
    "3_elem3"
    );
$arr = array_values($arr); // if our array has custom keys change it to consecutive numbers
try {
    array_walk($arr, function($val, $key)
    {
        $key++; // add 1 to the index ( because starts at 0)
        $pattern = "#".$key."_elem".$key."#"; // write down our pattern
        if(!preg_match($pattern, $val))
        {
            throw new Exception("Not in sequence: ".$val, 1); // if not in sequence then throw an error
        }
    });
    echo "Array has sequential values";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for "shortest", how about:

```
function check($array) {
    for ($i = count($array)-1; 0 < $i; $i--)
        if (1 !== ((int)$array[$i] - (int)$array[$i-1]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Start at the end walking backward, compute difference between this and previous element, if not exactly one return false. Otherwise return true.  Note the typecast to int is simple way to get leading digits.